# php preg_match css source code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code:

```
$date = 
  "<style>
    background-image:url(\"/hamza.png\");
    background-image:url(/hamza.png);
    background-image:url('/hamza.png');
  </style>";
```

I want to use`preg_match` to check if the url start with a slash.

This is what I have tried:

```
if (preg_match('url\(("|\'|)(?:\/)\1\)', $data) {
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';
}
```

It always gives me "no".
I would like to know what this code is for : (https?:\s*)?//.*?\1)

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use delimiters and also you need to match the chars which exists inside the brackets.

```
if(preg_match('~url\((["\']?)/[^)]*\1\)~', $data){
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pK1fV4/3)

Update:

```
preg_replace('~(background-image:url\(["\']?)(?=\/)~', '\1website.com', $data);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cH1gS7/8)

Comment: it replaces urls that start with two slashes not one

Comment: are you trying to match or replace? pls provide expected output.

Comment: I'm trying to to preg_replace using preg_match as a condition

Comment: just post the expected output you would get after preg_replace.

Comment: I want to replace background-image and add my url if the background-image:url('/hamza.png'); start with one slash of course

Comment: pfff nothing is working I don't know why I still have problem , can you tell me what is the code to add in my regex if I want url that starts with a / won't get replaced

Comment: sorry forget to escape single quote in the regex. Try now.

Comment: can you come to facebook to chat?

Comment: and if we found the answer I will post it here so others will get helped

Comment: can you tell me what this code means . please: (https?:\s*)?\/\/.*?\1\)

Comment: put that regex in http://regex101.com and then see the explanation at the right side.

Answer (score 0):

U can try this code

```
if (preg_match_all('/url\(\s*[\'"]?([^\'")]+)[\'"]?\s*\)/i', $date, $matches)) {
  echo 'yes';
} else {
  echo 'no';
}
```